# How to check multiples in php to abstract the following sequence of numbers

Tags: php

I have a for loop, and I want to write a function to abstract the following sequence:

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16
.............
```

So, in a somewhat "pseudo" code, the function would have to check multiples like so:

```
$i = 0;

for (condition) {
    $i++

    if ($i is 1, 5, 9, 13) do something
    if ($i is 2, 6, 10, 14) do something
    if ($i is 3, 7, 11, 15) do something
    if ($i is 4, 8, 12, 16) do something
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This quesion is really unclear.

Comment: @HamZa : to you, maybe.

Comment: @greg0ire it's been a while since I browsed SO's PHP feed. Maybe you're getting better at deciphering what the OP really meant?

Comment: I get how you're feeling right now. Too much SO ;) I'm just passing by, so I did not have to go through 10 hazy questions before. The modulo idea is difficult to express, especially if you don't know the word modulo, but I think OP did not do that bad of a job posting his question. The pseudo-code is formatted, and the example is pretty detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modulo operator. 1, 5, 9 or 13 modulo 4 is always 1.

Also you may want to use a switch / case statement, to avoid repeating the modulo 4 part.

```
<?php
switch ($remainder = $i % 4) {
    case 0:
        // and do another thing too
    break;
    case 1:
        // do something
    break;
    case 2:
        // do something else
    break;
    case 3:
        // do yet another thing
    break;

    default:
        throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf(
            'the remainder is %d, this is very strange!',
            $remainder
        ));
}
```

Comment: shouldn't case 4 be case 0? there should not be a remainder of 4 when dividing by 4.

Comment: @blots : totally, fixing that.

Comment: @blots : that's why you should always add a default statement to your switch construct, I guess.

Comment: and start your counter at 1